# C - How to avoid reading extra characters from stdin while waiting for a thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, client-server, stdin

I'm writing a client-server game in C (I can use standard libraries only). The server application creates a thread for each connected client to manage them. Client has to wait a given time in order to receive some data from the thread which handles it, then he sends data. The problem is that the user can write into terminal when it's waiting for data, so scanf (or similar) reads these things buffered before, and sends them to server as commands.

```
void game(int server_sd){
    char msg;
    char buffer[200];
    char buf[500];
    char row[16];
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int stdin_copy;
    read(server_sd, &playerLetter, 1); //Client waits for data. Here we can write into terminal and buffer into stdin
    while(1){
        system("clear");
        printMap(server_sd);        //Prints the map
        receiveMessage(server_sd);  //Receives a message from server
        clearBuffer();
        scanf("%s",buffer);  //This scanf reads the buffered stdin
        msg = firstChar(buffer);
        write(server_sd, &msg, 1); //...And then the client sends these dirty commands to server
        if(gameFinished){
            printf("Starting new game...\n");
            if(read(server_sd, &playerLetter, 1)<=0){  //Client waits for data. Here we can write into terminal and buffer into stdin
                break;
            }
            gameFinished = 0;
        }       
    }
}


void clearBuffer(){
    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { };
}
```

For example:
There are no active clients.
Client A is the first player.
Server sleeps for 10 seconds before starting a new game.
During this period I can write for example (new lines when I press enter):

```
q
d
s
```

These letters are buffered into stdin and so scanf automatically reads them. Client sends them to server with write(server_sd, &msg, 1).

clearBuffer clears the characters up to the first \n. 
I could not find a way to clear the whole stdin buffer.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

I tried `select`

```
int checkSTDIN(){
    fd_set rd;
    struct timeval tv={0};
    int ret;

    FD_ZERO(&rd);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &rd);
    ret=select(1, &rd, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    return (ret>0);
}
```

```
.
.
.
read(server_sd, &playerLetter, 1); //Client waits for data. Here we can write into terminal and buffer into stdin

while(checkSTDIN())
   getchar();
.
.
.
```

But it did not work

Comment: One way is to use `select` with a zero timeout. That will tell you whether there is any pending input. If there is, keep reading. But note that this whole approach has a race condition - there is no way to tell exactly which input was entered before `receiveMessage` and which was entered after. So your `clearBuffer` may end up clearing some input that it should not have.

Comment: @kaylum I tried `select` (I updated the post with the code). It reads all the characters I buffered but when it gets to the end getchar(), it waits for an input, then returns to the while and continues to read characters getting stuck in the while.
I need to block the while when select reaches the last character, ('\ n' after 's' in our case), it seems to still read something from the stdin when there is nothing.